# How to upload images from phone and store in mysql database in livecode

Tags: mysql, image-uploading, livecode

I am working in a livecode app.In which i need to upload images from my phone and store their encoded form in Mysql database and be able to retrieve those images after decoding.Do Anyone Have some reference regarding this. 
Thanks

Comment: You need to learn PHP :-)

Comment: hehhehe...But i got it this time without using PHP With the help of MobilePickPhoto .I encoded the image and store it in my database when i need to retrieve this image i simply decode that stored sting.Its working fine in Sqlite ,but i have not tried it with Mysql.As i am still not able to connect to MySql database on server.:(

Comment: Exactly. SQLite works local, but MySQL works with a (remote) server. Since your remote server doesn't allow for direct connections to the MySQL database, you need to learn PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The following link should be able to help you with retrieving data from a MySQL database via PHP in LiveCode-

http://www.vampire-tiger.info/livecode-server-side-script-and-remote-databases.html

In regards to your question about inserting images into a database, the following forum post might be of some assistance-

http://forums.runrev.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=488

Comment: Is it possible with Sqlite?
If i want to have a remote Sqlite which can be accessible by all the users using the application.